# What information is needed to write an abstract LDAP Integration Service

Tags: node.js, active-directory, ldap

I've been tasked with researching/writing an LDAP integration module to support any/all clients that use local LDAP authentication for our new app. As I've never worked with LDAP before, I'm trying to figure out what settings are required/not required, and what settings I'd need to capture from each LDAP system to be able to support them all. So if I'm storing data in a database about each LDAP server, what is needed about that server to be able to successfully auth with a username/password?

I see lots of ou/cn/dc references, but sometimes people don't use them in their connection strings? And unless pre-registered, it seems like I'd have no way of knowing the names of the groups/categories to query against.  I was thinking about the SAML spec and was curious if LDAP systems have an endpoint to retrieve some kind of XML describing their LDAP hierarchy?  Or if I'd just need to know/ask for it from a sysadmin in advance?

FWIW I'm using Node/ldapjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard way of describing the LDAP hierarchy in the manner you were considering. LDAP is in fact self-describing, you can search for a particular entry regardless of it's position in the LDAP tree by looking up one of its attribute's value.

So, to get started with completely unknown LDAP you only require it's network parameters: hostname, port (and even that can be avoided if you consult SRV DNS records (*_ldap._tcp.domain.com*)) and authentication details in the form of bind DN and password.

After that you can search for users, typically by looking up with filter like `(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)`, or groups of users with filter like `(objectClass=groupOfNames)`. Then you would use common attributes such as username, CN or displayName to reference or display the users in the user interface.

As you can see from this LDAP servers are very self defining and this ideally works for most LDAP servers, but as you perceived in your question it can differ from one LDAP server to another.

So here is my list of LDAP configuration settings that should be configurable:

- hostname/port number (if not using DNS discovery)
- username/password (if not using anonymous access)
- does the server use SSL (port 636 by default) (or detect support for StartTLS)
- user filter and user base DN (e.g. `(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)` and `o=users`)
- group filter and group base DN (e.g. `(objectClass=groupOfNames)` and `o=groups`)

Depending on your use case you could define what attributes are used for displaying the user, mapping them to other parts of your application/system  or you could determine those from the returned set of attributes. I've seen implementations that have that very configurable and implementations that default to some standard schema.